# How to use subject and debounce with RxJs 5 from a string input

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I do not get how the Subject object would work for a *Suggestion/Search service* that I'm trying to implement in Angular2.

Let's say that generateSuggestions gets called **each time an input changes**, for an autocomplete use.

I don't understand why I'm not able to get something out of the "next()" call, typescript compiler says it's returning a void type.

My goal would be to submit each change to an object, which will decide to call each 500ms a function on the server, without spamming it on each key entry.

```
import { Jsonp, Response, Http } from 'angular2/http';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    queryStream = new Rx.Subject();

    constructor(public http: Http) {

    }

    generateSuggestions(query: string) {
        this.queryStream
            .next(query)
            .debounce(500) // Compiler error: Debounce does not exist on type "void"
            .map(
                query => this.http.get('hellow')
                        .map( (res: Response) => res.json() )
                        .subscribe( results => console.log(results) )
            );
    }
}
```

I can do this in plain JS/Typescript but I really wanted to try to work with RxJs because it's already used by Angular2.

What are the mistakes made here? The documentation is really poor without any example on their official website.

Comment: You should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVI5gGTEQ_U) to see how to do a typeahead.

Comment: I have made some changes after seeing that video, and the rxJs subject is not part of the service anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note: if you have a better alternative, just post another answer and I will choose it as the answer.*

My results have shown that I was not understanding well the purpose of Rx.Subject.

---

### Suggested solution using ngModel and ngModelChange

Because I currently only use ngModel in my components, I had to split the [(ngModel)] to [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)

**In the component constructor**

Use an Rx.Subject (theorically it's the same than an EventEmitter, but maybe it has changed since because we don't have access to all the Rx.Subject methods with it anymore) that will be parameterized to debounce and call the service to retrieve values.

**For each keystroke:**

Input -> (ngModelChange) -> eventEmitterComponentInstance.next(InputValue)

### Code

SuggestMultipleStringComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  template: `<input [ngModel]="userInput"
                    (ngModelChange)="userInputChanged($event)" />`
  providers: [SearchService]
})
export class SuggestMultipleStringComponent { 
    private typeAheadEventEmitter = new Rx.Subject<string>();
    private userInput: string;
        
    constructor(private _searchService: SearchService) {
        this.typeAheadEventEmitter
                .pipe(
                   debounceTime(700),
                   switchMap(val => {
                      console.log('called once')
                      return this._searchService.callSomething();
                   })
                ).subscribe(results => {
                    console.log(results);
                }, error => {
                    console.log('error logged:');
                    console.log(error);
                });
      }

    userInputChanged(value: string) {
        this.userInput = value;
        this.typeAheadEventEmitter.next(value);
    }
}
```

SearchService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }
    
    callSomething() {
        return this.http.get('some/url')
                        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: This syntax is no longer valid, as `Subject.debounceTime` was removed at some point.

Comment: @spamguy yes now it will probably work through a pipe debounceTime(700). See https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime
I updated my answer.